# Remember me Persistent Cookie in C#

Tags: asp.net, cookies, persistent

I am doing a project in asp.net and tring to do Remember Me System. What I am trying to do is store ID of the user which is uniqueidentifier in cookie. But that cookie lasts only one day even though I set its lifecycle a year. Every morning I had to login to website, the cookie gets cleared.

```
HttpCookie userid = new HttpCookie("mb_login_userid", dr["UserId"].ToString().Trim());
userid.Expires.AddYears(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(userid);
```

I check the cookie after this code is run, it says it is not persistent cookie, it is session cookie. So it gets cleared everyday.

What can I do to make it persistent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Response.Cookies("userid").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
```

or

```
userid.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...This is the code for creating a persistent cookie

```
HttpCookie userid = new HttpCookie("userid");
userid.Values.add("mb_login_userid", dr["UserId"].ToString().Trim());
userid.Expires=DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
Response.Cookies.Add(userid);
```